# this как в jquery, но на javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.show').click(function() {
    let thisText = $(this).text();

    $(this).siblings('.search').fadeToggle().focus();

    if (thisText !== 'Скрыть') {
      $(this).text('Скрыть');
      $(this).siblings('.list').addClass('scroll');
    } else {
      $(this).text('Посмотреть все');
      $(this).siblings('.list').removeClass('scroll');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
div .search {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  display: none
}

.list {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.list label {
  display: block
}

.scroll {
  color: #999;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h4 class="title">Регион</h4>

  <div>
    <input type="text" class="search form-control">

    <div class="list">
      <label>
                <input type="checkbox" checked>
                <span>Абруццо</span>
            </label>
      <label>
                <input type="checkbox">
                <span>Альто-Адидже</span>
            </label>
      <label>
                <input type="checkbox">
                <span>Аминдеон</span>
            </label>
      <label>
                <input type="checkbox">
                <span>Апулия</span>
            </label>
      <label>
                <input type="checkbox">
                <span>Арагацотн</span>
            </label>
      <label>
                <input type="checkbox" checked>
                <span>Абруццо</span>
            </label>
      <label>
                <input type="checkbox">
                <span>Альто-Адидже</span>
            </label>
      <label>
                <input type="checkbox">
                <span>Аминдеон</span>
            </label>
      <label>
                <input type="checkbox">
                <span>Апулия</span>
            </label>
      <label>
                <input type="checkbox">
                <span>Арагацотн</span>
            </label>
    </div>

    <button class="show btn btn-primary">Посмотреть все</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Вот что я попытался сделать на javaScript:**

```
document.querySelectorAll('.show').forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        console.log('Click');
        this.textContent('скрыть');
    }.bind(this), false);
});
```

В консоле выводится "Click", а в текст не меняется, я по разному пробовал, ничего.

Comment: '.js__catalog-filter__show' я что то этого у вас в хтмл не наблюдаю

Comment: .js__catalog-filter__show где? И код в примере не работает

Comment: ПРостите, ни тот класс вставил. Подправил, теперь верный

Comment: @Aleksandr Предлагаю вернуть предыдущему ответу галочку!) Он все же был первым + правильный.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`textContent` - это свойство, а не метод. Должно быть `this.textContent = 'скрыть';`. И `bind` здесь не нужен.
Кроме того, здесь можно спокойно обойтись стрелочной функцией. Тогда все будет без this и по-современному...

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('.js__catalog-filter__show')].forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', e => {
        console.log('Click');
        item.textContent = 'скрыть';
    });
});
```

**Отредактировано:** вот вариант получше

```
const catalogClickHandler = () => {
    console.log('click');
    event.currentTarget.textContent = 'скрыть';
}

document.querySelectorAll('.js__catalog-filter__show').forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', catalogClickHandler);
});
```

Comment: Но насколько знаю... при таком подходе для каждого элемента будет создаваться отдельная функция, которая будет вынуждена запомнить ссылку на item? А если создать внешнюю функцию, и брать элемент через this - получится всего одна функция-обработчик, без лишних замыканий. Хотя это всё абсолютно не важно, если элементов всего 800) P.s. в современных браузерах у querySelectorAll есть встроенный forEach

Comment: OPTIMUS PRIME, можете привести пример, прошу, я просто очень хорошо все понимаю на примере, когда вижу все как работает.

Comment: Действительно, про этот момент не подумал, спасибо. Но все же лично я бы не возвращался ради `this` к function-конструкциям. Можно использовать `event.currentTarget` для доступа

Comment: @artomich, а что не так с this? или с function-конструкциями?

Comment: @Grundy, во-первых, с this в некоторых случаях могут быть проблемы. Во-вторых, упрощения синтаксиса - это хорошо. В-третьих, единообразие - это хорошо (если уж использовать стрелки, то использовать везде, где это возможно). В-четвертых, функцию, объявленную через const, банально нельзя изменить

Comment: @artomich _В-четвертых, функцию, объявленную через const,_ - а это тут как относится?

Comment: @artomich «если уж использовать стрелки, то использовать везде» — Один минус: const, const, const, сливаются если их много (и автор кода не разделил их пробельными строками), приходится вникать в блок, чтобы понять где функция, где вызов функции, а где - просто константа. А слово "function" сразу бросается в глаза)

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME, проблема действительно решается правильным размещением и разделением кода. То бишь, имхо, все же не повод пихать function :)

Comment: @Grundy, это я вдогонку привел, потому что стрелочные функции (не являющиеся колбеком какого-либо переборного метода) привычно создают константными. В свою очередь, как правило, функции, объявленные классическим способом, оставляют, как есть. Выражение, типа `const func = function() {}` в принципе не слишком эстетично...

Answer (score 1):

Ваша функция без jQuery:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  let btnShow = document.querySelectorAll(".show");
  for (let i = 0; btnShow[i]; i++) {
    btnShow[i].addEventListener("click", toggleList);
  } // При вызове функции, addEventListener и так привязывает this === btnShow[i]

  /***/
  function toggleList() {
    fadeToggle( this.parentNode.querySelector(".search") ).focus();

    let list = this.parentNode.querySelector(".list");
    // Это не то же самое, что siblings. Учитывая разметку - прокатит.

    if (this.textContent == "Скрыть") {
      this.textContent = "Посмотреть все";
      list.classList.remove("scroll");
    } else {
      this.textContent = "Скрыть";
      list.classList.add("scroll");
    }
  }
});



/*****/
function fadeToggle(elem) {
  var display = (getComputedStyle(elem).display);

  return display == "none" ? fadeIn(elem) : fadeOut(elem);
}

function fadeIn(elem) {
  elem.style.opacity = "0";
  elem.style.transition = "0.5s";
  elem.style.display = "block";

  setTimeout(function() {
    elem.style.opacity = "1";

    setTimeout(function() {
      elem.style.transition = "";
    }, 500);
  }, 0);

  return elem;
}

function fadeOut(elem) {
  elem.style.opacity = "1";
  elem.style.transition = "0.5s";
  elem.style.display = "block";

  setTimeout(function() {
    elem.style.opacity = "0";

    setTimeout(function() {
      elem.style.transition = "";
      elem.style.display = "none";
    }, 500);
  }, 0);

  return elem;
}
```

```css
div .search {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  display: none
}

.list {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.list label {
  display: block
}

.scroll {
  color: #999;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h4 class="title">Регион</h4>

  <div>
    <input type="text" class="search form-control">

    <div class="list">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" checked>
        <span>Абруццо</span>
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span>Альто-Адидже</span>
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span>Аминдеон</span>
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span>Апулия</span>
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span>Арагацотн</span>
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" checked>
        <span>Абруццо</span>
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span>Альто-Адидже</span>
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span>Аминдеон</span>
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span>Апулия</span>
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span>Арагацотн</span>
      </label>
    </div>

    <button class="show btn btn-primary">Посмотреть все</button>
  </div>
</div>
```